# android collapse invalidate calls?

Tags: android, view

Does Android collapse calls to invalidate method for View like Button, textview, ... ?
I created a complex view with different drawables which can each make call to the invalidate method of their view but I wish make only one draw operation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it does. However, if you invalidate a button, I believe the redrawing is clipped to just that button.